# Olingo OData 2.0 for Android - Dependency to javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory

Tags: android, odata, compatibility, classnotfoundexception, olingo

I tried to implement an *OData V2 Client using Apache Olingo OData 2.0 in Android*.

Executing the client class as java class works fine, but I cannot run the Android App using the same code in an AsyncTask:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.my.app.appname, PID: 2521
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.conurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.util.conurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;
at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.commons.XmlHelper.createStreamReader(XmlHelper.java:41)
org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.edm.provider.EdmxProvider.parse(EdmxProvider.java:50)
org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.ep.ProviderFacadeImpl.readMetadata(ProviderFacadeImpl.java:224)
org.apache.olingo.odata2.api.ep.EntityProvider.readMetadata(EntityProvider.java:844)
at connectivity.MyClass.doInBackground(MyClass.java:153)
at connectivity.MyClass.doInBackground(MyClass.java:38)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) <4 more...>
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.app.appname-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469) <12 more...>
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.stream.XmlInputFactory
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

My questions are:
**(How) Can I fix this issue?**
 (I read somewhere that the missing class might not be supported by Android?)
**Would it help to switch to Apache Olingo OData 4.0?**
(I need to consume an OData V2 service and if Olingo V4 would suport this on Android, I might try to migrate my client...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to repackage the javax.xml.stream classes yourself since Android does not support XML. Olingo V4 has a special android packaged client for that on the V4 dowload page: http://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/download.html

Olingo V2 does not have this feature because when the V2 library was created the main focus was on server side implementations. This is why a lot of convenience on client side is missing.